# Collection view crash on reloadItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have an uitableview with a collection view nested inside. Both the Collectionview and the Tableview have just 1 section. In the collectionview cells there are uiimageviews. I'm downloading pictures from a server, and when the picture is downloaded, I'd like to display them in the image view. I'm calling reloadItemsAtIndexPaths to reload the content of the cell to display the picture. This is what i found out so far:

if i'm using

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[secondArray indexOfObject:dictionaryToRefresh]]
```

as the index to refresh in reloadItemsAtIndexPaths, then the first picture loads just fine in the first cell of the collection view. The `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` does a nice fade-in effect too. Then it crashes badly with the error:

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView
>   _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44/UICollectionView.m:3835 2015-05-03
>   18:47:02.385 FBomb[3117:798045] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the
>   update'

if I use

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[secondArray indexOfObject:dictionaryToRefresh] inSection:0];
```

All the pictures load just fine! But there is no fade-in effect, which is what i'm trying to achieve. Any ideas as to I can overcome this issue? I'd like to display the pictures with the fade in effect (I really can't understand why it doesn't happens)

Thanks in advance and pardon typos!

**EDIT1
Full code:**

```
-(void) reloadItemWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionaryToRefresh{

        BOOL dictionaryFound = FALSE;
        NSIndexPath *= [[NSIndexPath alloc]init];
        NSIndexPath *indexPathSecondArray = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:0];

        for (NSDictionary *firstDictionary in megaArray)
        {
            NSArray *secondArray = [firstDictionary objectForKey:@"subArray"];
            if ([secondArray containsObject:dictionaryToRefresh]){
                indexPathFirstArray = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[megaArray firstDictionary] inSection:0];

                //THIS FADES THE FIRST ITEM ONLY, THEN CREASHES
                //indexPathSecondArray = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[secondoArray indexOfObject:dictionaryToRefresh]];
                //THESE WORKS, BUT THEY DON'T FADE
                indexPathSecondArray = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[secondoArray indexOfObject:dictionaryToRefresh] inSection:0];
                //indexPathSecondArray = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[secondoArray indexOfObject:dictionaryToRefresh] inSection:0];

                dictionaryFound = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( dictionaryFound == TRUE){

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                UITableViewCell *tableCell = [tableWithCollectionView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathFirstArray];
                UICollectionView *collectionViewInTableCell = (UICollectionView *)[tableCell viewWithTag:1000];

                    [collectionViewInTableCell performBatchUpdates:^{
                        [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathSecondArray]];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                    }];
            });
        }   
}
```

Comment: It really seems the only way to nicely fade in the pictures is calling collectionView reloadSections instead of collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPath....

Comment: So basically `[collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];` worked for you?

Comment: It works, but of course is reloading the whole section and that's not exactly what i want. I haven't been able to find another solution, though...

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try this instead:

```
NSUInteger x[] = {[secondArray indexOfObject:dictionaryToRefresh] , 0};
//I don't know if the first element is section or item. try both.
//NSUInteger x[] = {0, [secondArray indexOfObject:dictionaryToRefresh]};
NSIndexPath *path = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes: x length: 2];
[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path]];
```

`indexPathWithIndex` creates an instance by just using one `NSInteger` whereas `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` requires two values for item/row and section

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but it still behaves like indexPathForItem: it works, but the pictures appear all of a sudden, without fading in. One think it help me notice, though, is that for some reason indexPathWithIndex is reloading an item in the wrong section, and that's why it's crashing... how could it be?!

Comment: that explains also why indexPathForItem works (still not fading the pictures), it's because i'm specifying the section...

Comment: Then now I start to believe the fading is not about creating NSIndexPath. Can you post more code regarding the reloading part

Comment: Here you go! Added the code for the reloading method.

Comment: also, looking more closely, seems the the fading only occur when i'm reloading the whole sections... if so, is there a way to refresh the single item, with the nice fade in effect?